# It is possible to choose which fields render in the view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view wich use the `(initial{})` parameter to populate all the fields in the form but I don't need to show all the fields from the form.

I can just create another form and use the new form in the view but if exist other parameter like `initial` but with the function to choose fields will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying whether you want to change which fields to show depending on the state of the form or whether you simply want to exclude some.

In the latter case (exclude always):

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['fields', 'to', 'exclude']
```

If the exclusion is state dependent, you can use the form factory from Django:

```
if short_form_state:
    BookForm = modelform_factory(Book, fields=("author", "title"))
else long_form_state:
    BookForm = modelform_factory(Book, exclude=("created",))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function

Comment: I could do that in the forms.py but it is possible do the same in the function in the views.py?

Comment: Of course you can call the `modelform_factory` in your view. It makes actually more sense calling it in your view then anywhere else?